# Javascript Set Map regresa undefined en reduce

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, map

Tengo este array de objetos

```
const arr = [ 
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
                {name: "Oriental Olive", hex: "#445533"},
                {name: "Wicked Green", hex: "#9bca47"},
                {name: "Dreamless Sleep", hex: "#111111"},
                {name: "Leaf", hex: "#71aa34"},
                {name: "Cucumber Milk", hex: "#c2f177"},
                {name: "Emerald Forest", hex: "#224347"},
                {name: "Sea", hex: "#3c9992"},
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
            ];
```

Y lo regreso con un reduce para contar los repetidos

```
const res = Array.from(
                arr.reduce((m, {
                  name,
                  hex
                }) => {
                    var regresar = m.set(name, (m.get(name) || 0) + 1, hex)
                    return regresar
                }, new Map()), 
                ([name, count, hex]) => ({
                  name,
                  count,
                  hex
                })
            );

            //Regresa el hex como undefined
            console.log(res);
```

Regresa esto

```
0: {name: "Black", count: 3, hex: undefined}
1: {name: "Oriental Olive", count: 1, hex: undefined}
2: {name: "Wicked Green", count: 1, hex: undefined}
3: {name: "Dreamless Sleep", count: 1, hex: undefined}
4: {name: "Leaf", count: 1, hex: undefined}
5: {name: "Cucumber Milk", count: 1, hex: undefined}
6: {name: "Emerald Forest", count: 1, hex: undefined}
7: {name: "Sea", count: 1, hex: undefined}
```

**Como puedo hacer para que me regrese el tercer valor bien?
O alguna otra forma de contar los repetidos y crear un nuevo array de objetos con los (name) repetidos contados**

algo asi
{name: "Black", count: 3, hex: "#000000"}

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas intentando *reinventar la rueda*, cuando lo que buscas es relativamente sencillo:

1. Usamos un objeto auxiliar para poder contar las veces que aparece cada `name`.
2. Recorremos el *array* usando el auxiliar para contar.
3. Convertimos el objeto auxiliar en un nuevo *array*:

```js
const arr = [ 
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
                {name: "Oriental Olive", hex: "#445533"},
                {name: "Wicked Green", hex: "#9bca47"},
                {name: "Dreamless Sleep", hex: "#111111"},
                {name: "Leaf", hex: "#71aa34"},
                {name: "Cucumber Milk", hex: "#c2f177"},
                {name: "Emerald Forest", hex: "#224347"},
                {name: "Sea", hex: "#3c9992"},
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
            ];

function countRepeated( arr ) {
  const aux = { }
  
  arr.forEach( function( item ) {
    if( item.name in aux ) {
      ++ aux[item.name].count;
    } else {
      aux[item.name] = { count: 1, hex: item.hex };
    }
  } );
  
  const result = [ ];
  
  Object.keys( aux ).forEach( function( item ) {
    result.push( aux[item] );
  } );
  
  return result;
}

console.log( countRepeated( arr ) );
```

Con estos pasos, tan solo recorremos 1 vez el *array* original, y 1 sola vez el objeto auxiliar.

Observa que este código devuelve **un array nuevo**; el original se queda como estaba.

Answer (score 1):

**Esto debería ser de utilidad:**

```
const arr = [ 
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
                {name: "Oriental Olive", hex: "#445533"},
                {name: "Wicked Green", hex: "#9bca47"},
                {name: "Dreamless Sleep", hex: "#111111"},
                {name: "Leaf", hex: "#71aa34"},
                {name: "Cucumber Milk", hex: "#c2f177"},
                {name: "Emerald Forest", hex: "#224347"},
                {name: "Sea", hex: "#3c9992"},
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
                {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
            ];

const filterBy = 'name';
const result = [...new Map(arr.map(item => ({ name: item.name, hex: item.hex, count: arr.filter(elem => elem.name == item.name).length })).map(item => [item[filterBy ], item])).values()];
```

Comment: Deberías evitar los *one-line-code*...

Answer (score 0):

**texto en negrita**Yo lo solucione de la siguiente manera, espero te ayude. En el (for) comparamos que existan coincidencias con el nombre elegido.
Una vez encontrada las coincidencias las sumamos, con filter()creamos un nuevo arreglo que contengan las coincidencias con el nombre elegido. Object.defineProperty nos ayuda ha  agragar nuevas propiedades al array que contenga las coincidencias

```
const arr = [ 
            {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
            {name: "Oriental Olive", hex: "#445533"},
            {name: "Wicked Green", hex: "#9bca47"},
            {name: "Dreamless Sleep", hex: "#111111"},
            {name: "Leaf", hex: "#71aa34"},
            {name: "Cucumber Milk", hex: "#c2f177"},
            {name: "Emerald Forest", hex: "#224347"},
            {name: "Sea", hex: "#3c9992"},
            {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
            {name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
        ];




let iguales=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 
    if(arr[i].name==nombre()){
      iguales++
    }
}
let nuevoArray = [{}];
const nuevo = arr.filter(item =>{
  return item.name === nombre();
});
function agregarPropiedadesAlArray(obj){
 return Object.defineProperty(obj,'Count',{value:iguales});
}
function nombre(){
   return "Black"
}
console.log(agregarPropiedadesAlArray(nuevo[0]));
```